# How do I remove keywords affected by Google Local Pack in the Google Search Console API query?

Tags: api, google-api, google-search-console

Basically the data I get from the API includes keywords that has had their positions artificially increased by the local pack. This data is of no use to us and is misleading. Is there any way to remove it? I don't see any markers in the data query.

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We just used a 3rd part serp api to get what we want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).